# How can I use the module 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme' with Tailwindcss 2.2 CLI without installation?

Tags: command-line-interface, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss in my project, only with the CLI without installation, using this terminal command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i './tailwind_theme/custom.css' -o './tailwind_theme/tailwind.css' --jit --purge './**/*.php' -w
```

I used `npx tailwindcss init` to create the config file and would like to extend the default font family like this:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Lato', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
```

The response is

> Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme'

I checked the Tailwind CLI and config documentations and searched Google but nothing.

Is there a way to get it working?
Please be kind, it's my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

I also did my best, but couldn't overcome the problem.

One possible way that might help you is to have :

```
fontFamily: theme => ({
   sans: ['Lato', theme('fontFamily.sans')],
}),
```

But that didn't work for me, still worth a try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).